# MongoDB findOne() using $and on array elements

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a Schema as follows:

```
Schema = mongoose.Schema    
User= new Schema
    { name: String,
     phones: [
    {
      confirmed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      number: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
      }
  ]}
```

I need to make a findOne query that looks for a certain name or a phone number of a but only if it is confirmed
I tried the following but it is treating it as an or instead

```
const userFound = await User.findOne({
    $or: [
      { name },     
      { $and: [{ 'phones.number': phone }, { 'phones.confirmed': true }] }   
    ]
  });
```

Lets say i have the following document:

```
{"name": "foo", {"number": 1234, "confirmed": false}}
```

userFound is returning that document when my query parameters are `name=foo2 , number=1234`
Any ideas what i might be doing wrong?

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: I edited the question. Practically the query is returning matching phones even if they are not confirmed. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with $elemMatch allows you to match more than one component within the same array element.

```
phones: {$elemMatch: {number:1234, confirmed: true}}
```

Comment: Yup works like charm. Thank you so much saved me. Any idea how to put a unique index on number (i know i  have to code it in for inside the arrays) I need to make it unique accross documents. All material i read says it should work by just adding
`phones: [
    {
      confirmed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      number: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
      },
      token: String
    }
  ],`
But the index is not being created even tried from Atlas. I checked if the collection has existing duplicates but it is not! Thx again

Answer (score 1):

You are close.

This query do the job

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      "name": "yourName"
    },
    {
      "$and": [
        {
          "phones.confirmed": true
        },
        {
          "phones.number": 000000
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A7qhUGZXYid) with multiple values qhere only are returned those whose name is given or phone match but only if is confirmed.

Using `mongoose` is the same but with method `User.findOne(...)` or `User.find(...)`.

Looking again your answer, the query is almost the same... maybe I've misunderstood the question?
Please, check if mongo player results are ok to edit this answer if is not ok.

Comment: In your sandbox you if you search 
`db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      "name": "name3"
    },
    {
      "$and": [
        {
          "phones.confirmed": true
        },
        {
          "phones.number": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})`

Comment: you will get two results,
`[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "name": "name1",
    "phones": [
      {
        "confirmed": true,
        "number": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "name": "name3",
    "phones": [
      {
        "confirmed": true,
        "number": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]` 
I want only the results where phone is confirmed so it should be 1 result only!

Comment: Both results has `confirmed: true`.

Comment: you are right! so it was working!!! weird why i didnt get same result in my example.
I will check again and confirm.

Comment: I couldnt figure out why it is not working for me in Mongoose findOne()
I have the same query and i can see it works with find in your player but only $elemMatch worked with Mongoose!

Comment: `findOne()` will return only one document.

Comment: Yes but it is returning a ducument where confirmed is false!

Comment: This query will return a document which match: 1) Name or 2) Phone and confirmed. If you want a query that: 1) confirmed always has to be `true` and 2) Phone or name, one of them, can match. Then check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e7hZLF1U56s). Sorry if I've missundestood.

Comment: No i want what you said first. Name or a phone that is confirmed. You first player works exactly what i need but applying it on my model is not working. Very weird!

Comment: But `confirmed` has to be `true` always? If so try this [query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KNME3TscUBz). But with your restrictions, the original query should work... I don't know why works on playground and not in your DB.

Comment: Yes your first one was what i needed. Still cant figure why it didnt work. Sorry 
Do you have any idea about this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64731723/mongodb-unique-index-on-array-element-across-documents-not-across-nested-docume